# Change Language

Tags: languages, localization

My Hummer H5 smartphone came preloaded in Chinese.  I have changed the language setting for the phone itself to English however, the Google search is still operating in Chinese.  I would like to know what steps to take to change this to English.

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on the basic settings which is available throughout the
   Android Devices a phone has to display the default language
   throughout the phone through which the user can interact with the
   phone with ease.
2. Well If you have changed the default language to English under the Mobile
   Settings properly then it should display the default language for
   your phone throughout or else you might have not changed it properly(Chinese language has been categorised into many languages depending on the location like Simplified Chinese as far as I  know).
3. What I can suggest you is either you checkout with Customer Support
   or Check the instruction manual which should be available on the Web or in the Package with which the phone was shipped